# What is the name of this component? 2 pin, white connector

Tags: identification, components, component-selection

I need to buy the male side of this pictured component.

It is in a Kokoon moon door bell, and is white with 2 pins.

From hunting around, it could perhaps be a 2.54mm JST-XHP JST connector. I purchased a dupont type kit, that wasn't it.

- How do I tell?
- Could you give me some guidance on identifying it, so I get the right attachment?

[image: white 2 pin component]

Comment: For example, the other side might actually be called the female side, given the pins insert into it... the plastic inserts into the pictured part. 
Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Are you able to see anything on those headers ? Remove the PCB from its casing. Are you able to measure the pitch ?

Comment: it may be these ... JST XH connectors ... https://leeselectronic.com/en/category/2981-5mm-pitch

Comment: @MathieuG. which side is the pitch? I assume it is the shorter side or the visible rectangle, and would be the same for a 2 pin as a 4 pin right?
If I had a calipers, I could probably measure that right? Without removing the component?

Comment: Pitch is the distance between 2 pins. @Spehro Pefhany gave you the solution of your problem :)

Comment: Thanks @MathieuG.very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like JST XH series (2.50 mm pitch). Picture of the model is below (from Digikey).

[image]

Mating connector for the 4-pin would be the XHP-4, plus you have to buy the contacts separately, eg. SXH-001T-P0.6 for 22-26 AWG wire.

The official crimping tool is around $500 USD but there are cheaper ways to make a crimp that's probably good enough.

Comment: It is the 2 pin one, but agreed, the 2.5mm pitch - I assume the pitch is what I would describe as the width. ie. the 2 pin and the 4 pin have the same pitch and depth, but the length is different, for the extra 2 pins?

Comment: Pitch is the distance between pin centers. So the 4 pin one would measure 7.5mm between the two end pin centers if the pitch is 2.5mm. And part number for the 2 pin housing would  be XHP-2.

Comment: Thanks Spehro very helpful.